Can a .LZS file start with a 1 bit and still be considered LZS compressed?
I have written a program in Java that compresses and decompresses LZS encoded data. The LZS compression algorithm that I am referring to is the algorithm described in this paper:
https://web.archive.org/web/20220301223828/http://masters.donntu.org/2003/fvti/boykov/library/lzs.pdf
I wrote this program in hopes of decompressing an LZS file that I have access to. However, upon trying to decompress it, the program threw an exception. I looked at the LZS file in FreeFileViewer, and I almost immediately saw the problem. The first byte of the file is F3 (hex encoded). In binary, that is 11110011. In other words, the file starts with a 1 bit.
According to the way in which I understand the algorithm, LZS compressed data should always begin with a 0 bit, since the first byte of data would always be output as a raw byte (a 0 followed by the normal 8 bits of that byte). Therefore, an LZS file should not be able to start with a 1 bit.
Am I mistaken in my comprehension? Is there in actuality, some way in which a .LZS file can begin with a byte like F3 (and actually still be genuinely LZS encoded), or does this simply indicate that someone just simply chose to save the file as an LZS file even though the data is not actually LZS compressed?

Does the file have a header and what format would it be in? I would find it somewhat surprising (though not a huge surprise) if the file was just a raw LZS stream with nothing extra

@user555045 How do I distinguish whether or not a file has a header? That could be the case (that the file has a header), but how would I tell this? If it does have a header, how would I know which bytes of the file were the header?

Is the file format documented? Otherwise, if you have multiple files you can compare them and see which bytes stay the same and which change and how they change. The compressed data itself will likely be completely different between different files, but a header probably has some similarities. If you have only one file of an unknown format, that's a worst case and I don't really know how you could work out how to decode it.

It is possible that the compresion software assumes that the history buffer initialized to all zeros and are available for matching, so that first match would refer to a string of zeros.
